# Backbone app is trying to POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, backbone.js

I'm fairly new to Backbone so this is probably an obvious mistake...

I've created a customisable form with a few views. I'm pulling in my config data from config.json through my form collection. In the console I'm getting an error:

'POST http://local.ti-url-builder/js/config.json 405 (Method Not Allowed)'

Any ideas? I'm not doing any POST's (that I'm aware of?). I have a feeling its' related to the way I'm pulling the data:

```
TAG.FormCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: TAG.FormsModel,

    url: "js/config.json",
});
```

You can view the app here: https://di-campaign.s3.amazonaws.com/redirect/urlbuilder_v2.html

Thanks in advance for any help and useful criticism :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited the link you shared and saw multiple failed POST requests with HTTP status code 412. 
Those are getting triggered in form-view.js:

```
TAG.Section = new TAG.FormSectionCollection();
...
TAG.Section.create( pageAttributes );
```

The create method of Collection triggers POST request. It saves the model to the server and adds to the collection.

Comment: Great. So how do I stop it from doing that? :)

Comment: If you don't want to save it to server, use add method i.e. TAG.Section.add( pageAttributes );

Comment: Legend. Thanks so much. That's been bugging me for weeks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving a model instance? By default, if you save a model and it doesn't have an `id` value, a POST request will be sent to the url...

Comment: Erm... I don't think so. The only place I'm declaring a model is in my collection, as above.

Comment: ahh, I am doing: this.set( "formattedHeading", formattedHeading ); inside the model initialize function. Maybe this is triggering it? Can you elaborate a little more on setting an ID value. Thanks!

Comment: No, that shouldn't be it (unless you're automatically saving the model when attributes change). Regarding what HTTP request is sent on `save` see http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save (and of 1st paragraph)

Comment: No, just taking a value from the current collection, uri encoding it then setting it back. I've removed this and it still gives the error...